# iphone TCPSocket header files?

Tags: iphone, tcpsocket

```
#import <sys/socket.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
```

I have import the headers above,but

```
setsockopt(CFSocketGetNative(TCPSocket), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&yes, sizeof(yes));
```

show warnings "use of undeclared identifier 'TCPSocket'";do I need to import other header files?

add:

```
CFSocketContext CTX = {0,self,NULL,NULL,NULL};
    _socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, kCFSocketConnectCallBack, TCPServerConnectCallBack, &CTX);
    setsockopt(CFSocketGetNative(_socket), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void *)&yes, sizeof(yes));
```

I have insteaded TCPSocket of _socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is TCPSocket here?  It is supposed to a variable of type CFSocketRef.  It looks like you need to set that up first. Post more code and maybe we can be of more help.